# Print Screen of Current Webpage Screen using wcf( not using url )

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to take a screen shot of current screen(print screen of current screen as an image) using WCF service.
I have googled code and I found some code (like `memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen` ) and that is fine working in my local machine. but when I hosted on IIS server then it gives me an error that there is no screen on the server .

so is there any way to get a screenshot of a current web page as an image

**Note:**
I can not use http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ or any other tool which accept URL because my web page URL is same ...data is a render from jQuery.

**So without passing URL I want a screen shot of current web page.**

Comment: To be clear, you have a client accessing a website, and you want to take a screenshot of the webpage on the client, then send that image to the server via WCF?

Comment: Yes ...that is working on my local machine but its not working on server when i deployed it on iis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to take a screenshot of a desktop, the executable taking this screenshot must be running on the target device.

In your tests the executable (WCF service) is running on the webserver and will attempt to take a screenshot of the webserver when you execute it, not the client performing the WCF request.

You are left with a few options (that I can think of at the moment):

1) Use an application that can be installed on the client to perform the screenshot, and send the screenshot data to the WCF service.  This can be either a straight forward EXE with installer.  To make the user experience easy for the user it could be a ClickOnce deployment (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17003/ClickOnce-Quick-steps-to-Deploy-Install-and-Update)

2) Use some sort of plugin designed for the target browser.  Same rules apply, it runs on the client, takes the screenshot and sends the screenshot to the WCF service.  Probably a lot of work here to work with many browsers.

3) If you only want to take a screenshot of a web page from an application you own and modify the source of then you could write some javascript that essentially sends the current state of the DOM of the document to a WCF service and the service could then render the DOM on a kind of virtual browser.  E.g PhantomJS (http://phantomjs.org/), or Awesomium (http://www.awesomium.com/). Then save the rendered output.

Comment: Yea, thats what my answer is addressing